# Why does the command "git fetch -p" brings the same branch as deleted and new branch at the same time?

Tags: git, github

I have a weird "issue" (is not affecting me at all because the branch does exists locally and remote) and I am curious about it. I am not sure if this is a configuration I am missing or I do have but as I said is really weird.

Each time I do `git fetch -p` I got the branch `[deleted]` and `[new branch]` and the only difference is a capital letter in front of the branch name as shown in the example below:

```
λ git checkout development && git pull origin development && git fetch -p
Switched to branch 'development'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.
From github.com:ers/case
 * branch              development -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
From github.com:ers/case
 - [deleted]           (none)     -> origin/hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991
 * [new branch]        Hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991 -> origin/Hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991
```

Here is the result of the command `git config --list`:

```
λ git config --list                                                                                                                               
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt                                                                               
http.sslbackend=openssl                                                                                                                           
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain                                                                                                             
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f                                                                                                              
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f                                                                                                            
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process                                                                                                         
filter.lfs.required=true                                                                                                                          
credential.helper=manager                                                                                                                         
core.editor=nano.exe                                                                                                                              
core.autocrlf=true                                                                                                                                
core.fscache=true                                                                                                                                 
core.symlinks=false                                                                                                                               
core.autocrlf=true                                                                                                                                
winupdater.recentlyseenversion=2.23.0.windows.1                                                                                                   
user.name=reypm                                                                                                                              
user.email=<********>
alias.l=log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h\ %ad%Cred%d\ %Creset%s%Cblue\ [%cn] --decorate --date=short                                              
alias.lg='git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all'                                                                                             
alias.a=add                                                                                                                                       
alias.ap=add -p                                                                                                                                   
alias.aa=add .                                                                                                                                    
alias.ac=!git add -A && git commit -m                                                                                                             
alias.c=commit --verbose                                                                                                                          
alias.ca=commit -a --verbose                                                                                                                      
alias.cm=commit -m                                                                                                                                
alias.cam=commit -a -m                                                                                                                            
alias.m=commit --amend --verbose                                                                                                                  
alias.d=diff                                                                                                                                      
alias.ds=diff --stat                                                                                                                              
alias.dc=diff --cached                                                                                                                            
alias.a=add                                                                                                                                       
alias.ap=add -p                                                                                                                                   
alias.aa=add .                                                                                                                                    
alias.c=commit --verbose                                                                                                                          
alias.ca=commit -a --verbose                                                                                                                      
alias.cm=commit -m                                                                                                                                
alias.cam=commit -a -m                                                                                                                            
alias.m=commit --amend --verbose                                                                                                                  
alias.d=diff                                                                                                                                      
alias.ds=diff --stat                                                                                                                              
alias.dc=diff --cached                                                                                                                            
alias.s=status -s                                                                                                                                 
alias.co=checkout                                                                                                                                 
alias.cob=checkout -b                                                                                                                             
alias.b=!git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate' --format='%(authordate)%09%(objectname:short)%09%(refname)' refs/heads | sed -e 's-refs/heads/--'  
alias.la=!git config -l | grep alias | cut -c 7-                                                                                                  
commit.gpgsign=false                                                                                                                              
gui.pruneduringfetch=true                                                                                                                         
smartgit.submodule.fetchalways=true                                                                                                               
smartgit.submodule.update=true                                                                                                                    
smartgit.submodule.initializenew=true                                                                                                             
push.recursesubmodules=check                                                                                                                      
core.repositoryformatversion=0                                                                                                                    
core.filemode=false                                                                                                                               
core.bare=false                                                                                                                                   
core.logallrefupdates=true                                                                                                                        
core.symlinks=false                                                                                                                               
core.ignorecase=true                                                                                                                              
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:ers/case.git                                                                                   
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*                                                                                           
user.name=reypm                                                                                                                                 
user.email=<******>
branch.development.remote=origin                                                                                                                  
branch.development.merge=refs/heads/development                                                                                                   
branch.master.remote=origin                                                                                                                       
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master                                                                                                             
gitflow.branch.master=master                                                                                                                      
gitflow.branch.develop=development                                                                                                                
gitflow.prefix.feature=feature/                                                                                                                   
gitflow.prefix.bugfix=bugfix/                                                                                                                     
gitflow.prefix.release=release/                                                                                                                   
gitflow.prefix.hotfix=hotfix/                                                                                                                     
gitflow.prefix.support=support/                                                                                                                   
gitflow.prefix.versiontag=                                                                                                                        
gitflow.path.hooks=D:/dev/docker/case/.git/hooks
```

In addition to what I have said before I must say I am using Git from Windows.

I also notice `core.ignorecase=true` but I am not sure what would do if I change that to false or if I should keep it as true since I am in Windows and it's know to be problematic with file names and so on.

As a fun fact remote branches with capital letter does not exists in the origin:

```
λ git fetch -p                                                                                                         
From github.com:ers/case
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/Hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991                
 * [new branch]          hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991  -> origin/hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991   

λ git branch -r | grep DISPUTELAB-4991                                              
  origin/hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991
```

Does any see anything there leading to that "issue"? I am completely lost on this one.

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yup, forgot to mention that "small" part.

Comment: Definitely a case-sensitivity issue, but not really me area of expertise. Hope that at least helps your googling

Comment: I've seen lots of weirdness when butting up against case sensitivity issues.  For example, BitBucket, even when running on Linux, will sometimes treat refs that have different cases as the same ref, and sometimes as different ones.

I would recommend deleting all of the ones with the upper-case, both on the server and on user's local systems.

Nuke it from orbit.  It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @PortMan this isn't Bitbucket but Github also see my latest edit the remotes with capital in front of the branch names does not exists in the origin, odd issue as I mention in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`origin/hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991` is clearly totally different from `origin/Hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991`, in the same way that Polish and polish are two completely different words.<sup>1</sup>

Git understands this fact and handles it correctly.  Your OS, on the other hand, insists that `hotfix` and `Hotfix` are *the same*.  So you get weirdness around this case.

Git sometimes stores these names in a text file, where they are different, the way Linus Torvalds and Git intend them to be.  But sometimes Git stores these names in folder-and-file-names on disk, and then they become the same.  The `core.ignorecase` setting will not help, for two reasons:

1. It is purely informative: it tells Git *about* your system, but does not actually change anything Git does with file names.  (It probably should, but doesn't.)
2. It's only used for files extracted from commits into your work-tree, not for branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and other such references.

Git needs—and is gradually growing<sup>2</sup>—some better handling of file names inside repositories for these cases.  It also badly needs, but is *not* getting, better handling of branch and other reference names.  Because of this second issue, it's best to just use all lowercase letters for *all* branch, tag, and other names.  Just pretend uppercase does not exist: avoid it and you'll never find Git behaving weirdly on case-folding systems.

---

<sup>1</sup>The sentence "the Polish man applied shoe polish" makes sense; the variant with "the polish man applied shoe Polish" veers off into the weeds at the last moment. :-)

<sup>2</sup>This is linked to the ongoing sparse-checkout work.  That's one way to handle the problem, and it generalizes to other problems we encounter when using Git on both Linux and MacOS, for instance, with MacOS's insistence on normalizing file names like `schön`, although I think it's still not really quite right.

Comment: Thanks for answer and great explanation however I am creating branches as `git checkout -b hotfix/DISPUTELAB-4991` no capital letter for `H` there is my confusion.

Comment: @ReynierPM: someone—you or anyone else—used `Hotfix` some time in the past, so that your OS has a directory/folder named `Hotfix` lying around. Whenever your Git goes to create the new folder named `hotfix` instead, to hold your branch name, your OS says *oh, you must mean re-use the existing uppercase-h Hotfix* and puts the file in there instead (and then reports back *I created the file just like you asked* even though it actually changed the name!). So Git proceeds to think that it has a lowercase h `hotfix`, until it goes later to look and sees `Hotfix` instead: *hey, wait a minute...*

Comment: In effect, your repository has been "poisoned" by someone using uppercase H at some point. You can fix this—flush out the poison—by going into the `.git` directory and finding the uppercase-H `Hotfix` names and renaming them, in whatever OS-specific manner actually convinces *your* OS to do the job. Or, if it's not painful, you can throw away the entire repository and re-clone a fresh one that has never been poisoned and does not need to be cured.

Comment: Note that if *anyone*, anywhere, makes an uppercase-H `Hotfix`, that re-poisons your Git. (This problem does not affect Linux by default since its file systems are case-sensitive and therefore can hold both `Hotfix/foo` and `hotfix/bar`. That is, Linux is immune to this kind of poisoning.)